# Remove all escape symbols from String svg JAVA

Tags: java, svg

I am using this regex to remove all escape symbols from my string svg `.replaceAll("\\{", "{")` I tested it in a simple main method like and it works fine

```
System.out.println("<svg xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" version=\"1.1\" class=\"highcharts-root\" style=\"font-family:&quot;lucida grande&quot;, &quot;lucida sans unicode&quot;, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"600\" height=\"350\"><desc>Created"
        + " with Highcharts 5.0.7</desc><defs><clipPath id=\"highcharts-lqrco8y-45\"><rect x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"580\" height=".replaceAll("\\{", "{"));
```

When i tried to use this in my code there is no exception but the replace all function seems no to work.

```
@RequestMapping(value = URL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String svg(@RequestBody String svg) throws TranscoderException, IOException {

    String result = svg;

    String passStr = (String) result.subSequence(5, result.length() - 2);

    passStr = passStr.replaceAll("\\{", "{");

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(passStr).array());
    service.converter(is);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you want to parse XML, use an XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "abc\\{}def";
    System.out.println("before: " + test);
    System.out.println("after:  " + test.replaceAll("\\\\[{]", "{"));
}
```

**Output**

```
before: abc\{}def
after:  abc{}def
```

Comment: Same as previous regex. I can not understand why it works only when i start it in a main method but when i am using it in my code the regex do not work.

Comment: Yes i noticed that and i tried your solution but same again. It works obly when i am using it in main method but not in my application as shown in my first post.

Comment: passStr = passStr.replaceAll("\\\\[{]", "{");
        System.out.println(passStr);

On this line i saw that there are no changes after call replaceAll method. No idea why ?!?

Answer (score 0):

Your first example doesn't have any "{" characters, so I'm not surprised it works (??).

But anyway, your regex is wrong.  Backslash is in an escape character in both Java Strings **and** in regular expressions. So `\\` in a string just means `\`. That means your regex is actually just `\{` , which just means `{`.  So all you are really doing is replacing `{` with `{`.

If you want to make a regex that replaces `\{` with `{`, you need to double each of your backslash characters in the regex: `\\\\{`.